# how to encode/encrypt a structure before write to file

Tags: c++

I have a struct like this:

```
struct ITEM
{
    INT         ItemNum;
    BYTE        Kind;
    char        ItemName[200];
};
```

I write ITEM structure to file without encode like this, no problem.

```
ez_map<INT, ITEM>::iterator itrItem = mapItem.begin();
while (itrItem != mapItem.end())
{
   ITEM *pItem = &itrItem->second;
   WriteFile(hFile, (LPCVOID)pItem, sizeof(ITEM), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
}
```

I try to cast the structure to array of byte then encode this array and copy back to struct like this:

```
ez_map<INT, ITEM>::iterator itrItem = mapItem.begin();
while (itrItem != mapItem.end())
{
   ITEM *pItem = &itrItem->second;
   //begin to encode
   BYTE bytesArr[sizeof(ITEM)];
   memcpy(bytesArr, &pItem, sizeof(ITEM));
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(ITEM); i++){
      bytesArr[i] ^= 1;
   }
   memcpy(&pItem, bytesArr, sizeof(ITEM)); //crash here, because NULL character was xorred.
   //end encode
   WriteFile(hFile, (LPCVOID)pItem, sizeof(ITEM), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
}
```

I also try with CryptEncrypt, &pItem as pbData, and sizeof(ITEM) as pdwDataLen but no luck.
Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: You should write and read your byte array, encode before writing and decode after reading. Also note that you assume a fixed endianness by accessing the integer `ItemNum` as a sequence of bytes. You will not be able to exchange the file between systems of different byte orders.

Comment: There is no reason to save the encoded data back into the `ez_map`.  Simply copy the item to a byte array, encode the byte array, and then write the byte array to the file. Don't modify the original item. When reading back the file, simply read an item into a byte array, decode the byte array, and then copy the byte array into the `ez_map` as needed.

Comment: In both of your memcpy calls you must pass `pItem` instead of `&pItem`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `&pItem` on the second `memcpy()`. You are copying to the wrong destination memory address. It needs to be like this instead:

```
memcpy(pItem, bytesArr, sizeof(ITEM));
```

However, this second extra copy is not needed. You can use code like this instead:

```
while (itrItem != mapItem.end())
{
   ITEM *pItem = &itrItem->second;
   //begin to encode
   BYTE* pb = (BYTE*)pItem;
   int n = sizeof(ITEM);
   do *pb++ ^= 1; while (--n);
   //end encode
   WriteFile(hFile, pItem, sizeof(ITEM), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
   // may be decode Item here if need
}
```

Or, in case `pItem` must be read-only:

```
while (itrItem != mapItem.end())
{
   ITEM *pItem = &itrItem->second;
   //begin to encode
   BYTE bytesArr[sizeof(ITEM)], *pc = bytesArr, *pb = (BYTE*)pItem;
   int n = sizeof(ITEM);
   do *pc++ = *pb++ ^ 1; while (--n);
   //end encode
   WriteFile(hFile, bytesArr, sizeof(ITEM), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
}
```